# Spring MVC: manage BindingException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a problem with the binding of a form input text to a Integer field of the bean to which the form is binded. If I write a wrong number in the input text (eg: "12b") I have a Binding Exception. So, I set a @InitBinder in my controller in this way:

```
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Integer.class, new CustomIntegerBinder());
    }
```

Where CustomIntegerBinder is implemented as follows:

```
    public class CustomIntegerBinder extends PropertyEditorSupport {

        @Override
        public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            try {
                setValue(Integer.parseInt(text));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //I WANT TO ADD ERROR TO THE ERROR LIST!
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String getAsText() {
            return getValue().toString();
        }
    }
```

My question is: how could I succeed in adding a message error to the errors list, so that a conversion error would not cause a crasch of the application, but a message to be printed in the "errors" tag in the jsp?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setAsText` method should throw an `IllegalArgumentException` (as the method signature indicates) if the value can't be set from text.

If you throw the `IllegalArgumentException` from your `catch` then Spring should add the error for you.

Comment: I did try, but I have the stack trace in the browser that reports me the IllegalArgumentException. In the Stack trace I can read: 
       
"Field error in object ... java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: incorrect Value]"

That is, in the stack trace I have all the information that I need (about the field and the type of error) but I don't know I to prevent the stack trace from being printed in the browser and how to get the information about the error and to add them in the errors list.

Comment: The "Field error" means it _is_ being added to your errors, so it must be something else - can you post the code for your controller method that handles this request?

Comment: Ah.. It is so strange... I did change the order of the parameters of the method and now everything works fine! Now the signature of the method that handles the request is "(@ModelAttribute("opera") OperaDTO dr, BindingResult errors, Model model)", while, before, "model" was declared before "errors". Thank you, now it is all right!

Comment: `BindingResult` has to be placed after the parameter which is validating. If not, validation will not work or `BindingResult` will not fill correctly!